# Spring Batch, one reader call sends several models to processor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch job that calls a web service in the reader which returns a list of up to 1000 records.  I would like to have the processor run on each record individually so the commit interval doesn't have the minimum of 1000.  Can a single reader call produce multiple process calls if it returns a list?

From what I have found so far this may be possible but not worth the effort and I may be better off just having the reader return a list of objects and the processor processing up to 1000 records each read call.

Comment: Have you implemented a custom ItemReader? How do you call the web service?

Comment: Right now we do have a custom itemreader that calls a service and gets back (for simplicity here) an arraylist of 1000 strings.  I would like to process strings individually, rather than passing out the array to the processor and making it do all 1000 at once.

Comment: Fine. Can you please post code for a simplified `ItemReader` you have to take a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This links might be helpful.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor.html

[How to configure a Spring batch job with single reader and calling multiple writers depending on object returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330171/how-to-configure-a-spring-batch-job-with-single-reader-and-calling-multiple-writ)

Comment: Not quite, I don't need to run it on several different processors/writers, just the same one independently.  I can have the processor contain subprocessors, but if my understanding is correct, it will still commit records in batches of 1000.  So for one read, I want 1000 processor calls with a commit size of 10 for example.